# Sorting algorithm is skipping the last element in my array

Tags: algorithm

I have a simple algorithm to order numbers in an array, all of the elements become ordered except for the last one. I have tried changing the bounds of my loops to fix this, but it just creates an infinite loop instead.

Comment: Where is your getUsed() method. Be-sure that there you have only `array.length` and not `array.length-1`

Comment: the getUsedSize() just returns usedSize

Comment: What is used size?It's selection sort and you have to check whole list. Try this: `for(int i = pointer+1; i <A.length; i++)` btw  your swap method is also not correct.

Comment: used size is equal to A.length, i tried your suggestion but the program continues running a loop and never terminates

Comment: Please expose the code for the `swap` and `getUsedSize` functions, along with the type declaration of that `A` array.

Comment: i've edited to include this

Comment: I'm afraid it's not enough. You didn't show how you declared and instantiated the `A` array. And what's that while loop without an enclosing method ?

Comment: What's with the -1 in that `getUsedSize() - 1` ? That makes your algorithm skip the last element when searching for the minimum.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (pointer < arrayLength){
    int min = findMinFrom(pointer);
    for (int i = pointer; i < arrayLength; i ++){
        if (A[i] == min){
            swap(i, pointer);
            pointer ++;
        }
        compNewS ++;
    }

}
```

You see what's the problem? Your pointer will be updated only if `A[i] == min` if not then it will keep looping. Put your `pointer++` out of that condition.

This can be done with only two loops but here is an adjusted version of your code:

```
public class Numbers {

private static int [] A ;

 public static void main(String [] args) {
     int [] array = {3,2,1,4,5,6,7,8,9,7};
     A = array;
     newSort(array, array.length);
     for(int i = 0; i < A.length;i++)
         System.out.println(A[i]);
 }

public static void newSort(int[] array, int arrayLength){
    int pointer = 0;
    int p = 0;
    while(p < array.length) {
        int min = findMinFrom(p,array);
        int temp = array[p];
        array[p] = min;
        array[min] = temp;
        p++;
    }
}



public static int findMinFrom(int p, int[] array){
    int min = p;
    for (int i = p; i < array.length; i ++){
        if (A[i] < array[p]){
            min =i;
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

}

Comment: The pointer is supposed to be inside the if loop, moving it outside doesn't fiz the error

Comment: Moving out the `pointer++` instruction makes the program terminate, but it also makes it incorrect.

Comment: It will fix the error and your implementation is totally wrong. Can you tell me how many elemnts you have same in on array? in a array of 10 elements if 5 are equal to min then pointer will never reach array.length and loop will never break;

Comment: SelectionSort finds minimum from whole list then swaps it with first element and then finds again minimum for 2 to n and swaps it with second element and so forth.

Comment: There are 5 elements in the array, all of the elements are different numbers

Comment: Unordered: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 'Ordered': 2, 3, 4, 5, 1